# Ingresa un número cualquiera. Luego muestra la suma de los divisores del número e indica si el número es perfecto

Tags: javascript

¡Hola! Tengo un problema respecto a un ejercicio que me dieron en clase y es hacer lo siguiente en JavaScript.

> Ingresa un número cualquiera. Luego muestra la suma de los divisores del número e indica si el número es perfecto.

> Un número es perfecto, si la suma de sus divisores, sin incluir el número, es igual al número. Ejemplo `6 = 1 + 2 + 3`

Quisiera conocer ideas vuestras, mi planteamiento fue el siguiente pero no está del todo correcto.

```js
var msj = prompt("Ingresa un número");

for (var i = 2; i <= 500; i++) {
    b = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= (i / 2); j++) {

        if (i % j == 0) {
            b = b + j;
        }
    }
    if (b == i) {
        console.log(" es un número perfecto");
    }
    else {
        console.log(" no es un número perfecto");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? ¿Dónde está el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu implementación debes sacar del ciclo el if y utilizar el valor de número que te introduce el usuario.

Te adjunto tu código corregido:

```js
var numero = Number(prompt("Ingresa un número"));
var sumaDivisores = 1;
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.ceil(numero/2); i++) {
    if (numero % i == 0)
      sumaDivisores += i;
}

if (sumaDivisores === numero)
  console.log(`${numero} es un número perfecto`);
else
  console.log(`${numero} no es un número perfecto`);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!